# Pytesseract cant read text from xray image

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I cant read the text embedded in the image with this simple code. What would be the reason?

```
img = Image.open("/content/xray4.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng")

print(text[:-1])
```

[image: xray4.jpg]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Pytesseract recognize plain white text on black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456014/why-cant-pytesseract-recognize-plain-white-text-on-black)

Answer (score 0):

1. tesseract will work better if you invert the image so the black text will be on white background.

```
255 - img  # something like this
```

[image]

2. you may need to set `psm` parameter depending on how the text located in the image. In your case `psm=6` will work:

```
6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.
```

Please check different options here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/main/doc/tesseract.1.asc#options

3. you may need to filter the recognized texts using some confidence threshold.

Results:

```
['Patient' 'Name:' 'SMITH' 'WILL' 'Q']
['Accession' 'Number:' '1234567']
['Patient' 'ID:' '987654']
['Exam' 'Description:' 'NECK' 'XRAY']
['Exam' 'no:' '47512']
['Date:' 'Jul' '8' '2004']
```

Example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("xray.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
scale_factor = 1600.0 / np.max(img.shape[:2])
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=scale_factor, fy=scale_factor)

df = pytesseract.image_to_data(
    255 - img, lang="eng", config="--psm 6", output_type=pytesseract.Output.DATAFRAME
)

# group recognized words by lines
for line_num, gdf in df.groupby("line_num"):
    line_confidence = gdf["conf"].mean()
    if line_confidence < 30:
        continue

    gdf = gdf[gdf["conf"] >= 90]
    if not len(gdf):
        continue

    print(gdf["text"].values)
```